# Why java += get wrong result, and how can I prevent this?

Tags: java

Why java `+=` get wrong result, and how can I prevent this problem? (for example any way show `warning` in IDE?)

I tried eclipse & IntelliJ but both not show any warning.

Sample code:

```
    {
        long a = 20000000000000000L;
        double b = 90.0;
        a += b;
        System.out.println(a); // 20000000000000088 NG
    }

    {
        long a = 10000000000000000L;
        double b = 90.0;
        a += b;
        System.out.println(a); // 10000000000000090 OK
    }

    {
        long a = 20000000000000000L;
        double b = 90.0;
        a += (long) b;
        System.out.println(a); // 20000000000000090 OK
    }
```

Comment: @Sotirios That question doesn't explain why a number with no fractional portion would have this behavior.

Comment: @4castle The precision of `double` doesn't only apply to its fractional portion.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That is the exact piece of information that question does not contain. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2607316/5743988) even *recommends* scaling the numbers to whole numbers because "integer arithmetic in floating-point is exact".

Comment: ***REQUIRED READING***: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think the question duplicate. It can explain why `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`  but not `10000000000000000 + 90 = 10000000000000088`

Comment: It's the same question of precision. Try `System.out.println(20000000000000090d);` and you'll see the same thing. Let me try and find a better duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and that answer not explain `how can I prevent this problem? (for example any way show warning in IDE?)`

Comment: Alright, I'll reopen.

Comment: @andyf The reason for both those behaviors is the same.  `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in floating point.  Neither can `10000000000000090`.  The mantissa doesn't have enough bits.  I suppose you could argue that in the case of `0.1` there could never be enough bits but in the second case adding bits would solve the problem.  All adding bits does is _move_ the problem.  It's always there with numbers of large enough magnitude and precision.

Comment: This question gets asked over and over again.  It is a duplicate, maybe not exactly a dup of the question referenced by @SotiriosDelimanolis, but a dup nonetheless.  I _know_ it's an exact dup of an answer I wrote a couple of years ago... I'll go find it.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for your reference. I think for most coders, they just need a tool (IDE etc) for telling them that not coding like that. I tried eclipse & intellij but both not show any warning.

Comment: @andyf The IDEs assume you understand floating point, just like they expect you to understand that integer overflow is silently ignored.  Floating point numbers are a powerful idea but they act differently enough from our "intuition" that they must be studied and understood for what they are.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for your answer. But, as not all programmers(like me) can always notice this problem, I found a simple way: just forbid `+=` as coding rule. See my answer.

Comment: That is just plain silly.  It has nothing to do with `+=` and everything to do with the fact that floating point has limited precision.  You'll have the same problem if you write `a = a + b` instead.

Comment: @JimGarrison but the IDE will show me the compile error while `a=a+b`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the JLS, this [compound assignment expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

```
a += b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (long) (a + b);
```

Since `b` is a `double`, [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) occurs before the addition happens. Both operands are converted to `double` values and the addition happens with floating point arithmetic.

The value `20000000000000090` cannot be represented exactly as a `double` and therefore you lose precision, getting `20000000000000088` instead. It then gets cast back to a `long` which has enough precision to represent `20000000000000088`.

Your second snippet produces `10000000000000090` which can be represented exactly as a `double`.

Your third snippet is equivalent to

```
a = (long) (a + (long) b);
```

which uses [integer arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2). `20000000000000090` can be represented as a `long`.

I don't know of any tools to warn you about this.

Related:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [64-bit IEEE floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which use 53 binary digits to represent the significant. In the first example,

```
{
    long a = 20000000000000000L;
    double b = 90.0;
    a += b;
    System.out.println(a); // 20000000000000088 NG
}
```

Here the variable `a` is converted to a double that must use an exponent greater than 1 to represent it, and it will no longer be an exact representation of the value 20000000000000000L.

In this example, it is possible to represent `a` using only the significand and an exponent of 1.

```
{
    long a = 10000000000000000L;
    double b = 90.0;
    a += b;
    System.out.println(a); // 10000000000000090 OK
}
```

In this example, `b` is explicitly converted to a long, avoiding the need to convert `a` to a double and perform floating point arithmetic.

```
{
    long a = 20000000000000000L;
    double b = 90.0;
    a += (long) b;
    System.out.println(a); // 20000000000000090 OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As not all programmer(like me) can understand [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)、

For preventing such `+=` coding missing, I found a simple way: just forbid all `+=` as coding rule.

I just grep all `+=` in my projects, and change `a += b` to `a = a + b`.

IDE shows errors while type not match while `+` operation, as bellow:

[image: IDE show compile errors]